# не работает callback с url

Tags: python, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"]) # Реакция на текст
def reaction(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    message_id = message.message_id
    if message.text == ' Баланс':
        data = get_profile(chat_id)
        #bal = q.execute(f'SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id = "{message.chat.id}"').fetchone()
        #connection.commit()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Ваш баланс: {list(data)[2]}₽')
    elif message.text == ' Клик':
        data = get_profile(chat_id)
        profile_button = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        profile_button.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Перейти', url = url[data[3]], callback_data='NewPayment')
        )
        bot.send_message(chat_id,"Перейдите по сайту для получение денег", reply_markup = profile_button)
        #q.execute(f'UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 0.1 WHERE user_id IS "{message.chat.id}"')
        #connection.commit()
```

нужно сделать проверку на переход по ссылке, но callback не работает с атрибутом url

Answer (score 0):

У вас прописан только обработчик сообщений, а от inline keyboard приходят callback_query. Вам надо добавить соответствующий обработчик

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(....)
def handle_query(...):
    ...
```

Comment: Он прописан ниже, просто он не работает когда указан атрибут url, а мне нужно что бы при нажатии были хоть какие то выходные данные